# Spark - CSV text loading parsing error

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am using following code to load a csv file that has text/notes in it.

```
val data = sqlContext
      .read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")
      .load(dataPath)
      .na.drop()
```

Notes are not in any specific format. During loading I am getting this error:

```
com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: Error processing input: null
Identified line separator characters in the parsed content. This may be the cause of the error. The line separator in your parser settings is set to '\n'.
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Do any records from the file span more than one line, i.e. does your data have have `\n` characters inside what you consider to be "one record"?

Comment: Problem, the way I see it, is with "" or [[ kind of characters. And, yes, there are \n characters. But, I need spark to treat /t/n as one record. Why is it treating \n...

Answer (score 2):

I do not have privilege to comment on question, I'm adding answer.

As you are doing `na.drop()`, may use `option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` as well.

```
val data = sqlContext
      .read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")
      .load(dataPath)
      .na.drop()
```

BTW, **databricks spark csv** is inbuilt in Spark 2.0+